# Looking for Synonyms/Adjacent Terms for Traditional Media Publishing Companies

Tags: single-word-requests

Some quick context: I'm writing a paper on how modern social media platforms (Facebook, Twitter, Snapchat, TikTok, etc.) perform unlike any other method of mass media distribution that has come before, and the problems that are caused by those differences. Specifically, I'm focusing on how social media enables any regular person's exact, unscrutinized words to be seen by huge numbers of people across the globe, whereas even 15 years ago one's message would need to go through some form of media publication company where it would be checked for quality, reviewed, and likely revised before being published and seen by a more limited demographic of consumers.

Obviously I'm making a ton of A/B comparisons here; I'm trying to avoid sounding like a broken record with every one. I don't mind repeating "social media" again and again, but I'm looking for more words to describe the other side.

---

I'm looking for terms that describe traditional media publication companies; specifically those that take an original work (either created by an outside party or in-house), put it through some form of vetting/revision process, then market that work to the general public. Here are some specific examples:

- Umbrella terms for the entire group as a whole, like "traditional
  media publishers", "media conglomerates", etc...
- Slightly more specific *categories* of those companies, like "movie/film
  studios", "publishing houses", "newspapers", "radio stations" etc...

To be clear, I'm looking for general terms that fall into this field, **not names of actual companies**, so please don't answer with "Scholastic Publishing House", "Fox News", or "Disney/Pixar Studios".

Any terms you think *might* fall into this category are appreciated as well as ones that obviously do. Basically, please don't limit things to only print, film, or broadcasting platforms. If it's something that generally acts as a vector for distributing someone's original work, idea, or message to more people than the creator could feasibly do as an individual, just toss it in there, but novel ideas aren't a requirement.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Traditional media companies (and the editors who work for them) are sometimes called "gatekeepers" of public discourse. Is that the kind of term you're looking for? (By the way, you can find several terms for this type of media at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_media.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, Thanks! "Gatekeepers" is *absolutely* on point in this context, though unfortunately I beat you to that one... not sure why I hadn't included it as my main example since it's basically the key term I'm building around. The wikipedia article was definitely helpful though; so far I'd managed to completely gloss over music as a form of expression - feeling a bit sheepish about that one. :P So now in that vein I have "record label", "recording studio", etc.

Comment: Wikipedia's also a great place to click around and look for more, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Traditional media contrasts with social media. But the difference you refer to is **edited** media as opposed to raw and anonymous.